# How do I figure out the language generated by this context-free grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages

I am dealing with the following grammar:

```
G = ( {S, A}, {a, b}, P, S ) 
P = { S -> aAb, S -> bAa, 
A -> aSa, 
A -> S, 
A -> epsilon}
```

I need to find out L(G).
The thing is, I figured out that the words in the grammar are of the form: 
starts with a and ends with b, or starts with b and ends with a, and between these letters one of the combinations : ab, ba, aaba, abaa; then the next word is formed by inserting one of these 4 combinations between the a and b in the middle..but how can I express this formally?
I mean, as far as I could tell, L(A) = a^n S a^n and if w belongs to L(G), then w reversed also belongs to L(G).
I tried to express it as a regular expression but failed...could anyone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: The context free grammar already defines the language, What more do you mean by "find out L(G)"?

Comment: he probably wants to define language using operations as ^r, \, *, ., ... etc, or to write a regular expression, I'm at work now so I don't have time to check but I don't think it's regular language, maybe it can be expressed with the operations above, I'll look at it at home

Answer (score 1):

You see that L is not regular, to prove you can use [Pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma) or [Myhill–Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem), so regular expression can't be discussed

You can notice, that since L consists just of {a,b} you can use it's power
We see that language is in the form of aAb or bAa or aAa with exception that aAa can't be located at begin-end of the word

So let's use this, the only thing we miss is the combination of bAb
A can generate almost everything (words |w| = 2k, and |w|>=2) but words where position of b matches position of b from the reverse

Formally
[image]

Sorry for my tex skills and my formal expression

there must be some error, because I didn't have so much time to think about this, but it can be some way how to continue, it's homework so it's fine, think about it! :)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to express it as a regular expression but failed

This language is 'probably' not regular. Context-free languages are more complex/powerful than regular expressions.

Try generating a few words and see if you can come up with a name, properties for the language. Or try to find words that are *not* in the language.

Some hints, a few properties you can easily see:

1. The smallest string is at least size 2.
2. The size of the string is even.
3. The count of b's is <= than a's.

If you take out `A -> aSa`, and compare a word with its reversed version, a pattern should be visible. If you include the left out rule, the pattern changes slightly...

Answer (score 0):

You are asked to find the language generated by the grammar *G* with productions

```
S → aAb | bAa
A → aSa | S | λ
```

First, consider small derivations beginning from the start symbol *S*

```
S ⇒1 aAb ⇒1 aaSab | aSb | ab

S ⇒1 bAa ⇒1 baSaa | bSa | ba
```

The difficult step is dealing with the recursion generated by the rules *A* → *aSa*, *S* → *aAb* and *S* → *bAa*. The clue to dealing with this difficulty is revealed by considering an inductive definition of the language generated by *G*:

```
1. ab ∈ L4
2. ba ∈ L4
3. w ∈ L4 → awb ∈ L4
4. w ∈ L4 → bwa ∈ L4
5. w ∈ L4 → awa ∈ L4
```

The rules (3)-(5) correspond to the rules *A* → *aAa*, *S* → *aAb* and *S* → *bAa* in *G*. It is easy to see that the inductive definition and the rules of *G* define the same language. The inductive definition shows that the language of *G* can be build incrementally in steps. Starting with the smallest strings generable in *G*, we build larger and larger sets of strings corresponding to the problematic rules:

```
L(1)     = {ab, ba}
L(n + 1) = {awb, bwa, awa : w ∈ L(n)}
```

The set *L*(1) contains the smallest strings generable in *G*. The set *L*(n + 1) contains strings *awb*, *bwa* and *awa* for each string *w* ∈ *L*(n). That is, the strings in *L*(n + 1) correspond to the strings obtained by applying the rules *S* → *aAb*, *S* → *bAa* and *A* → *aAa* once to strings in *L*(n). All that remains is to construct the union of the *L*(n), which is a set:

```
L = ⋃ {L(n) : n ∈ ℕ}
```

To see that *L* is equivalent to the language generated by the grammar *G*, you can argue by induction on the length of derivations in *G*. Starting with the smallest strings genreable in *G* (i.e, *ab* and *ba*), working backwards using appropriate induction hypotheses.

Answer (score -1):

the language generated is : (a)<sup>n</sup>(b)<sup>m</sup>  Were n>=m

Comment: Wrong. Even ba is in the language.