# Language generated by a Context Free Grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar, language-theory

How to find the language generated by a context free grammar? And for the language generated, how can I justify, that the language belongs to that grammar.

Please give some hints, or maybe a specific example. I came across [this post] ([How do I figure out the language generated by this context-free grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8123485/1332886)), but it was not so helpful.

Comment: You can only learn by practice. You need same aptitude and reasoning skills as you need for programming. Pick some good book read chapter-read examples. solve questions given in problem-sheet at back of each chapter -- But problem is you have to put efforts

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [*Introduction to the Theory of Computation*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/113318779X) by Michael Sipser for an in-depth explanation and a number of practice problems.